# Encrypting PayPal Button

Tags: php, button, encryption, paypal

I am dynamically enrypting my Paypal buttons but when clicking on the "Subscribe" button I am getting an error from Paypal: "Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information".

The code I am using to generate my button:

```
<form id="suf" onsubmit="return newUser();" action="<?php echo $PPBtnURL; ?>" method="POST">
    <?php
        $form = array();
        $form['business']=$PPbtnUser;
        $form['itemname']=$_POST['item_name'];
        $form['itemnumber']=$_POST['item_number'];
        $form['currency_code']="USD";
        $skip_a2 = ($res['a2'] <= $res['a1']);
        foreach($res as $k=>$v){
            if($skip_a2 && ($k == "a2" || $k=="p2" || $k=="t2")){continue;}
            if($k == "trial1" || $k == "trial2"){continue;} 
            $form[$k]=$v;                                   
        }
        $form['src']=1;
        $form['rm']=2;
        $form['return']="https://www.mysite.com/signup2.php";
        $form['cancel_return']="https://www.mysite.com/";
        $form['bname']=$_POST['bname'];
        $form['fname']=$_POST['fname'];
        $form['lname']=$_POST['lname'];                         
        $form['pwone']=$_POST['pwone'];
        $form['pwtwo']=$_POST['pwtwo'];

        $encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form); 

        function paypal_encrypt($hash){
            global $MY_KEY_FILE;
            global $MY_CERT_FILE;
            global $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE;
            global $OPENSSL;

            // private key file to use
            $MY_KEY_FILE = "/home/mysite/mysite.com/prvkey.pem";
            // public certificate file to use
            $MY_CERT_FILE = "/home/mysite/mysite.com/a62ecbe3015a2165c8859b953753038a-pubcert.pem";
            // Paypal's public certificate
            $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE = "/home/mysite/mysite.com/paypal_cert.pem";
            // path to the openssl binary
            $OPENSSL = "/usr/bin/openssl";

            if (!file_exists($MY_KEY_FILE)) {
                echo "ERROR: MY_KEY_FILE $MY_KEY_FILE not found\n";
            }
            if (!file_exists($MY_CERT_FILE)) {
                echo "ERROR: MY_CERT_FILE $MY_CERT_FILE not found\n";
            }
            if (!file_exists($PAYPAL_CERT_FILE)) {
                echo "ERROR: PAYPAL_CERT_FILE $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE not found\n";
            }

            //Assign Build Notation for PayPal Support
            $hash['bn']= 'StellarWebSolutions.PHP_EWP2';

            $data = "";
            foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
                if ($value != "") {
                    $data .= "$key=$value\n";
                }
            }
            $openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
                "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";
            exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);
            if(!$error){
                return implode("\n",$output);
            }else{
                return "ERROR: encryption failed";
            }
        };
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="<?PHP echo $encrypted; ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I followed the steps and used most of the example code [here](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php).

**What might be causing this error?** I have no errors from PHP.

Bonus question: What logfile is Paypal referring to?

Comment: which server log? there's nothing in my ipn log and there's nothing from php, like i said. besides how would paypal have access to any of the logs on my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit late now, but if it helps: I was getting that same error after following that same tutorial and although I can't see the issue in your code I found that I would get this error whenever there was something in the $form being passed into paypal_encrypt() that PayPal didn't like.

tl;dr: invalid data in $form can trigger this "helpful" error

Also, be aware that you are passing data from $_POST directly into the $openssl_cmd without escaping it.